Left motor not moving backward in Arduino L298N motor control project
Problem Description:
I’m working on a project where I’m controlling two motors using an Arduino and L298N motor driver, but the left motor doesn’t move backward when I send the reverse command. Here’s what I’ve done so far, along with the troubleshooting steps I’ve followed.
System Details:
Controller: Arduino
Motor Driver: L298N Motor Driver
Connections:
Left Motor: Connected to OUT1 and OUT2 of the motor driver.
Right Motor: Connected to OUT3 and OUT4 of the motor driver.
Separate L298N board is used for a pump motor.
Questions:
Motor Control Code:
The code works fine for forward, right, and left movements. But when I press the backward (B) command, only the right motor moves backward while the left motor does not.
What could be the reason the left motor isn't responding to the backward command while everything else works as expected?
Wiring and Multimeter Tests:
I’ve checked all the connections and confirmed them multiple times.
I used a multimeter, and the signals sent from the Arduino are correct (HIGH and LOW). I’ve tried with three different L298N motor driver boards, and the issue persists.
Is there any specific wiring configuration or setup step that might be causing only the left motor to fail in reverse?
Motor Testing:
I connected the left motor directly to the power supply, and it works both forward and backward.
Does this rule out the motor being faulty, or could there be another reason it still doesn’t work in reverse when connected to the motor driver?
Motor Driver Issue:
The motor driver’s forward function works perfectly, but when I send the reverse command, the left motor fails to rotate.
Could this be an issue with the motor driver itself, even though I’ve tried multiple boards? If so, what further tests can I perform to confirm this?
Arduino Pin Reassignment:
I tried reassigning Pin 6 (left motor reverse) to a different pin (e.g., Pin 10) to rule out an issue with the Arduino, but the problem persists.
Could this indicate a software or hardware issue, and how can I isolate the problem?
Enable Pins on L298N:
The ENA pin for the left motor driver is connected properly (I’ve used a jumper for testing).
Is there any scenario where the ENA pin could fail in reverse mode but still work for forward movement?
Power Supply:
The power supply I’m using is adequate, and I’ve tested with different sources. Could an insufficient power supply still cause the left motor to fail in reverse only, while everything else works fine?
Other Factors:
I’ve also considered possible issues like internal shorts, wire defects, or broken connections, but these seem unlikely after testing different boards and components.
Are there any other factors that I might be overlooking?
Additional Context:
The right motor responds correctly in all directions (forward, backward, left, right).
The issue is isolated only to the left motor when I try to reverse.
I’ve used a separate L298N board for the pump motor to avoid confusion.
code :
const int leftMotorForward = 7;  // IN1
const int leftMotorReverse = 6;  // IN2
const int rightMotorForward = 5;  // IN3
const int rightMotorReverse = 4;  // IN4

void setup() {
    pinMode(leftMotorForward, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(leftMotorReverse, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(rightMotorForward, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(rightMotorReverse, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    char command = Serial.read();
    
    if (command == 'F') {
        moveForward();
    } else if (command == 'B') {
        moveBackward();
    } else if (command == 'L') {
        turnLeft();
    } else if (command == 'R') {
        turnRight();
    } else if (command == 'S') {
        stopAllMotors();
    }
}

void moveForward() {
    digitalWrite(leftMotorForward, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(leftMotorReverse, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorForward, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorReverse, LOW);
}

void moveBackward() {
    digitalWrite(leftMotorForward, LOW);
    digitalWrite(leftMotorReverse, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorForward, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorReverse, HIGH);
}

void turnLeft() {
    digitalWrite(leftMotorForward, LOW);
    digitalWrite(leftMotorReverse, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorForward, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorReverse, LOW);
}

void turnRight() {
    digitalWrite(leftMotorForward, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(leftMotorReverse, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorForward, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorReverse, LOW);
}

void stopAllMotors() {
    digitalWrite(leftMotorForward, LOW);
    digitalWrite(leftMotorReverse, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorForward, LOW);
    digitalWrite(rightMotorReverse, LOW);
}
```


Please add a schematic diagram as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Good initial debugging steps. Please provide the following tests/info. 1 Disconnect the L298 and issue the back command to the Arduino. Verify with a multi-meter (or logic analyzer if you have one) that the four pins are doing what you expect. 2 Disconnect the L298 from the motors. Manually command the pins responsible for reverse (short them to 5V with jumpers). Measure the voltage on each motor output jack and check if it is what you expect. 3 When connect the motor directly to the power supply, can you somehow measure its current draw? If power is insufficient, this will tell.

i am checking with multimeter when i click forward function its show both side 12 v left function 12 v appear right function also same but backward function onside -12 v show another side 0.01 shows
if its problem with power insufficient why bot motors rotating forward
am also manually check i cant find the issue

@Sharathi Please try the second and third tests, exactly as described in my comment, with the L298 disconnected from both the motors and disconnected from the Arduino. We want to isolate the problem, so we must test one thing at a time

also please clarify the pins for each output of the l298n board to the arduino. So far from your question/statement the left reverse motor is pin 6. Do the same for all of the pins. This is really useful when we want to help you debug your issue.
